# Deleting a daemon thread only after it returns

Tags: c++, locking, pthreads

I'm working on a project in which I have a main thread and one daemon thread to perform file outputs. In my main thread I have a field `pthread_t * _daemon` that I would like to delete, but obviously only after `_daemon` returns NULL (I understand that using `pthread_exit()` cause memory leaks).

How can I do it without busy-wait? If I try to use a condition variable I have a problem - When I call `signal()` form `_daemon` to wake up my main thread, it deletes `_daemon` before it `_daemon` returns NULL.

What I did is to just use a mutex lock that is locked when the program is launched and unlocked before `_daemon` returns. Is there any better way that would not cause busy wait?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What precisely would you like to delete?

Comment: The pthread_t field, but only after the daemon thread stored there returns

Comment: Do you want some other thread to wait for that thread to terminate for some reason? Or do you want the thread to clean up after itself automatically when it's done?

Comment: `pthread_exit()` does not cause any more or less memory leak, then exiting a thread without calling it.

Answer (score 5):

[`pthread_detach()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/pthread_detach.html) does what you're looking for. It sounds like it will solve your problem (no leaking) with a lot less complexity!

So you can safely call `pthread_detatch(_daemon)` when you're done with it inside the other thread, without having to worry about if the thread itself is still running. It does *not* terminate the thread, instead it causes the thread to be cleaned up when it does terminate.

From the documentation:

> The `pthread_detach()` function shall indicate to the implementation
>   that storage for the thread thread can be reclaimed when that thread
>   terminates. If thread has not terminated, `pthread_detach()` shall not
>   cause it to terminate.

You can actually create a thread in the detached state to start with by setting `attr` of:

```
   int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

appropriately at creation time. The `pthread_create()` manpage says:

> When a
>   detached thread terminates, its resources are automatically released back to
>   the system. [*snip*] Making a thread detached is useful for some types of daemon
>   threads whose exit status the application does not need to care about.  By
>   default, a new thread is created in a joinable state, unless attr was set to
>   create the thread in a detached state (using pthread_attr_setdetachstate(3)).

Comment: But _deamon that I want to free is in the main thread, not in the daemon thread. I want to delete this field only after the daemon thread terminates

Comment: @yotamoo: A `pthread_t` object can be deleted before the thread associated with it returns or is otherwise done. The thread itself doesn't rely on the `pthread_t` object - deleting the `pthread_t` object doesn't destroy the associated thread.  But you may need to call `pthread_detach()` to let the system know it can clean up all thread resources when the thread returns or exits.

Comment: @alk: I assume that the OP dynamically allocates a `pthread_t` (or a struct containing it) using `malloc()` or `new` and wants to `free()` or `delete` it.  However, that may be a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: @MichaelBurr - that would be a bit odd though given that my understanding is that on most (many?) implementations `pthread_t` is a typedef for a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_t` is an `unsigned long int`, so I don't really see a need to make a pointer of `pthread_t` (you can as well use it's address in `pthread` functions), but if you insist, then you can delete it after creating a `pthread` (but then you will have no way to communicate with it, because it's a number of created thread - used for joining, detaching functions etc.).